# Xcode 5 Architecture i386 multiple duplicate symbols

Tags: ios, xcode

I found the source folder for architecture i386, by copying the path specified by the error message in Xcode. There were several .o files which apparently were conflicting, however whenever I deleted one, and ran the program, it would replace it. What do I do? Also I've cleaned it and closed everything and restarted my computer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The .o files are just the compiled versions of your source code, which is where the conflicts really lie.  What you have is several things named the same thing, and the linker is stressing out over it.  Take one of the error messages, you'll probably identify the name it says is conflicting (not the file, the symbol), it might have extra padded symbols, but you should recognize a method name or variable name that you used.  Search for that in Xcode, and see where you're defining it more than once.  A symbol can have only one definition, so if you're using it in multiple cases, you need to resolve that.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Xcode, how do I find symbols in my source code? Also what are padded symbols?

Comment: The duplicate symbols are: symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController, symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ViewController. Where would I find these?

Comment: Defined the class differently in the other file, now I have 12 errors and 32 warnings?

Comment: Did you name something ViewController twice?

Answer (score 0):

## Possible Issue

This problem usually happens when you import .h files to `Compile Sources`.

## Possible solution

***Steps to clean project***

1. Click on your project
2. Select target of your project
3. Go to **Build Phases**
4. Expand **Compile Sources**
5. Remove all files there

***Steps to configure it again***

1. On **Compile Sources** click + to add files again
2. Highlight .m on search
3. Add all .m files to your project
4. Clean project by going to **Product**->**Clean** on **XCode** **Menu**

Click run, and hope it will work!