# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 - RegisterMonoModules

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, linker, armv7

so i just tried to distribute my ios project. 
The project is created in Unity and is using Google Play Services and Unity Ads.

After solving a lot of linker errors (related to Google play and Unity Ads) where i simply just needed to include some missing frameworks to the "Link binary with libraries" section then now i just ran into another linker error that i just don't know where it is coming from or how to solve.

This is what i get :

**Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "__GetNoTrackFlag", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules-DC9EF89F0E4F4A47.o
  "__GetCFBundleID", referenced from:
      RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules-DC9EF89F0E4F4A47.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Comment: check this asnwer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255338/xcode-5-architecture-i386-multiple-duplicate-symbols/23263985#23263985

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your project (or some of its dependencies) are not built for your expected architecture. If you're trying a "Release" build, make sure that you have "Build Active Architecture Only" set to "No" (it should be by default).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However "Build Active Architecture Only" is already set to "No".

Comment: Do you have multiple projects building in your workspace? Make sure that their "Architectures" settings all allow armv7.

Comment: No i only have one project and everything is set to allow armv7.

Comment: Is RegisterMonoModules your source code? Perhaps you haven't properly exported GetNoTrackFlag and GetCFBundleID and they ended up locked within a class file that's inaccessible to RegisterMonoModules at link time.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the **DeviceInfo.framework** from your XCode build.

You can add it manually for now, the next update to the package will resolve most of these post build processing issues.

I had these exact issues, and adding DeviceInfo.framework did the magic for me.

Remember to check that UnityAds.framework is there as well. 
They should be located in your projects > Assets > Plugins > iOS.